# Selecting value based on variable name of data frame column in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame with a few columns containing values, and a column containing the name of the relevant column. e.g.

```
df <- data.frame(p1=c("A", "B", "A"),
                 p2=c("C", "C", "D"),
                 name=c("p2", "p1", "p1"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

What I want to do is to retrieve a value from the column specified by the `name` field, i.e. the output as below.

```
> df
  p1 p2 name value
1  A  C   p2     C
2  B  C   p1     B
3  A  D   p1     A
```

I currently get by with `df$value <- ifelse(df$name=="p1", df$p1, ifelse(df$name=="p2", df$p2, NA))` , which is inelegant and unscalable if there are more than just `p1` and `p2`.

Any suggestion on a better approach for this?

Comment: I didn't understand that "using a loop" part; I thought `apply` and family doesn't use loops, unlike `for` etc?

Comment: Also, I have to admit I may not understand your code clearly enough to be comfortable reusing them. the `diag` one works perfectly but I don't understand what it did.

And for my education: why `cbind(seq_len(nrow(df))` instead of simply `1:nrow(df)`?

Comment: You could use either one, but I used `seq_len` for cases with `0` rows of `df`.  Anyway, it is okay for me.  I was a bit curious..  Regarding the `diag`, it would be very inefficient because you are creating a huge dataset and then taking the diagonal.

Comment: Thanks for the benchmark. I'd still be interested to know what happened with the `diag`, because that is the shortest answer after all.

Comment: The idea is simple, `df[,df$$name]` creates a dataset with columns based on `df$name`.  So obviously, many columns are repeated.  When you do diag, it extracts the diagonal elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
df$value <- df[cbind(seq_len(nrow(df)), match(df$name, names(df)))]
```

The above is a vectorized solution.  Or if you need only a compact solution (based on the number of characters)

```
diag(as.matrix(df[,df$name]))
#[1] "C" "B" "A"
```

#### Benchmarks

```
df1 <- df[rep(1:nrow(df),1e5),]

akrun <- function() {df1[cbind(seq_len(nrow(df1)),
                     match(df1$name, names(df1)))]}
colonel <- function() {apply(df1, 1 ,function(u) u[u['name']])}

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(akrun(), colonel(), times=20L, unit='relative')
#Unit: relative
#  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#  akrun()   1.0000   1.0000  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000    20  a 
#colonel() 118.2858 102.3968 46.25946 77.92023 59.15559 23.56562    20   b
```

Comment: this is working fine with my data class is data frame. But when my data is in data table it is throwing errors.

Comment: @PPC You can convert it to `data.frame` i.e. `setDF(yourdata)` and check if that works

Comment: Currently I converted DT to DF, and then this is working fine.But this is only workaround solution. I am looking for something that can be done using DT only.

Comment: @PPC You can do `setDT(df)[, value := get(name), 1:nrow(df)];df$value
#[1] "C" "B" "A"`

Answer (score 1):

Or very simply (but using a loop):

```
df$value = apply(df, 1 ,function(u) u[u['name']])

#> df
#  p1 p2 name value
#1  A  C   p2     C
#2  B  C   p1     B
#3  A  D   p1     A
```